# App crashes when I use my own .csv file to draw a polyline

Tags: ios, csv, nsarray, mapkit

I want to draw a route on a map taking the coordinates from a csv file. I built two sample codes (from The Reluctant Blogger) and they worked fine with the original csv files, but when I used a converted gpx file to csv (using GPSBabelFE), the app crashes with the following error:

> 2013-06-21 02:46:10.606 os4Maps[10178:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x31bbb3e7 0x398b6963 0x31b0621d 0x484af 0x48151 0x339e9579 0x47e81 0x33a2aaa1 0x33a2a625 0x33a22833 0x339cad1f 0x339ca7ad 0x339ca1ef 0x356e25f7 0x356e2227 0x31b903e7 0x31b9038b 0x31b8f20f 0x31b0223d 0x31b020c9 0x33a2146d 0x33a1e2b9 0x47dfd 0x39ce3b20)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

Does anybody know why is this happening?

I've checked the file and is not empty and, in my opinion, is ok.

The latest sample is from [here](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136) and the modified csv file is [here](http://pastebin.com/8TLLz2f2).

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the file to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), and update the question with a link.

Answer (score 0):

At which point in your code does this happen? Did you try to set breakpoints?

From the linked code, you have three occurrences of `objectAtIndex:` in the for-loop. The first one should be fine, but you may want to assert that `[latLonArr count] == 2`:

```
NSArray* latLonArr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];

assert([latLonArr count] == 2);

CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[latLonArr objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[latLonArr objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
```

Comment: I set a breakpoint and the app crashed at **/ create a c array of points. 
 MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * pointStrings.count);** I think the converted file is the guilty, I opened it on TextEdit to remove blanks and the commas at the end of the coordinate pairs. Microsoft Word adds characters, so TextEdit might do the same.